# "No finished builds" displayed for build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I have lots of build configurations that recently (I think today) started getting the status "No finished builds for this configuration ", although there have been lots of finished builds. The history tab shows them all, latest running yesterday.

Why don't the status reflect the correct value?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please submit bug report to our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW BTW, does server restart helps?

Comment: @PavelSher thanks, will try a restart and submit a bug

Comment: Strange - it works today, without a restart... Will keep an eye on it a few days now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has disappeared without any visible reason. No restart was made, and I have filed a bug report on JetBrains bug tracker.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20699